# Can we show equivalence of two distributions based on their statistics?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, machine-learning

Let $p,q$ be two distributions on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Under what conditions does $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}f(x,z)=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim q}f(x,z)\ \forall z\in\mathbb{R}^d$ indicate $p=q$ a.e.? For example, can we prove $p=q$ a.e. when $f(x,z)=\tanh(x^{\top}z)$?

(Note: this problem may be related to discriminatory functions such as sigmoidal functions, but two distributions are involved in this case.)

Comment: So with that $f$ and with $d=1$, this is asking: if for all $z$, $$\int (p(x)-q(x))\tanh(xz)\, dx =0,$$ does it follow that $p=q$ as distributions?

Comment: This is related to the moment problem. You need really strong conditions on $f$ and the space of possible 
distributions.

Comment: @ChristianChapman, it is related but the moment problem is usually about only moments from integer powers, and the analog here would be asking whether distributions are determined by their moments from non-integer powers as well. Eg in the standard example (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-5823-5_6.pdf) the lognormal and its perturbation only agree on moments for integral powers.

Comment: The answer to Matt's version (his comment above) is clearly *no* since $\tanh xz$ is odd, so the integral will be zero for all $z$ as soon as $p-q$ is even (so in particular, for any two even $p,q$).

Comment: I found a useful material. See Lemma 1 in https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/gretton12a/gretton12a.pdf

Comment: The term to search for is 'seperating classes' of functions. Such a class $\mathcal{M}$ has precisely the property that $\int fdP=\int fdQ$ for all $f\in\mathcal{M}$ implies $P=Q$. Classical refernce might be Ethier/Kurtz Markov processes. Also, e.g. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82419637.pdf